# How to catch the value of XML on the basis of XML attributes

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a sample XML file as below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Results>
    <Test testres="Fail">
        <Id>1234</Id>
        <mailId>Person1</mailId>
        <empName>Person1Name</empName>      
    </Test>
    <Test testres="Pass">
        <Id>4321</Id>
        <mailId>Person2</mailId>
        <empName>Person2Name</empName>      
    </Test>
</Results>
```

I Want to get the ID where `testres = "Fail".`
I have tried below script.

```
$XMLfile = 'D:\Powershells\PowershellXML\demo.xml'
[XML]$Results = Get-Content $XMLfile

$HowManyTimes = 1

for ($i=1; $i -le $HowManyTimes; $i++)
{

    foreach($Result in $Results.Results)
    {       
        Write-Host "Employee mail Id :" $Results.Results.Test | Where-Object  {$_.testres -eq "Fail"}.ID
    }
}
```

Please suggest the changes that I need to make in the scripts

Comment: Leave a space before `-eq`

Comment: @Theo : Tried it. still not getting the results

Comment: `$Results.Results | Where-Object  {$_.Test.testres ...` -> `$Results.Results.Test | Where-Object  {$_.testres ...`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I have made the changes as per suggestion.. Still not getting  ID as `1234`. Please see the updates in this question

Comment: `($Result.Test | Where-Object  {$_.testres -eq "Fail"}).ID`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen : Thanks, It worked.

Comment: write-host doesn't write to the pipeline

Comment: @js2010: The idea is to run the commands using those attributes.